# arkit scene view is only display 1 arkit object

Tags: swift4, arkit, touchesbegan, sceneview

My code below is only displaying 1 arkit object in the touches began function. I would like the user to be able to display several of the same arkit objects in the arkit scene view. Right now the user is able to place a image but as soon as the next one is placed the other one is deleted.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //Handle the shooting
    guard let frame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else { return }
    let camMatrix = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform)
    let direction = SCNVector3Make(-camMatrix.m31 * 5.0, -camMatrix.m32 * 10.0, -camMatrix.m33 * 5.0)
    let position = SCNVector3Make(camMatrix.m41, camMatrix.m42, camMatrix.m43)
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/dontCare.scn")!

    // Set the scene to the view
 sceneView.scene = scene
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly Milly, you are changing the whole scene each time, instead, add nodes to the sceneView.scene

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


guard let frame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else { return }
let camMatrix = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform)

let position = SCNVector3Make(camMatrix.m41, camMatrix.m42, camMatrix.m43)
let object = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/dontCare.scn")!.rootNode
object.position = position

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
```

}

Comment: In what function do I put this code in. I tried putting this in touches began but it did not work.

Comment: you can keep it in touches began. I think the issue you have is the position. You would need to perform a hit test on the real world. Try the Placing Objects code from Apple.

Comment: This does not work in touches began object node is not being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add multiple child node on ARSCNView

[image: if your .scn file structure something like]

```
let careScene = SCNScene.init(named: "art.scnassets/dontCare.scn")
let childNode = (careScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Frame", recursively: false))!
childNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
scenView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(childNode)
```

Comment: What function do I put this code in touchesBegan? When I put it in there it causes a compile error.

Comment: Yes, You can put on touchesBegan. Which error are you getting ?